# How Iterate in Webclient Flux and replace some value

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I am a newbie in WebClient. I want to consume a rest service and replace some value and return the result.

this is the response I get from rest service:

```
[
    {
        "type": "somthing",
        "details": {
            "d1": "va1",
            "d2": "va2",
            "d3": "va3"
        }
    },
    {
     .....
    },
    ...
]
```

This is the result I want to return to the user. (the new value is something that I get from the user, so I have it as a parameter.)

```
[
    {
        "type": "somthing",
        "details": {
            "d1": "va1",
            "d2": "va2",
            **"d3": "Replace with new value"**
        }
    },
    {
     .....
    },
    ...
]
```

```
Flux<Item> items= webClient.get()
                .uri("------URL------")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Item.class)
```

Above code correctly return items from the rest service and traditionally I can use `collectList().block()` to get a List and replace the value inside the object and return it.

I feel that it is an old-fashion way. Is there any better way to handle this situation by using WebClient functionality?

Comment: [`Flux::map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: Thanks, I used map before asking the question but my mistake was I returned a new object rather than edit the current one and return the same obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @michalk I used map and it worked.

```
Flux<Item> items= webClient.get()
                .uri("------URL------")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Item.class)..map(item-> {
                    item.getDetails().setDThree(request.getValue);
                    return item;
                 });
```